# How to forward sms to selected contacts to whatsapp from my Android app?

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, whatsapp

Here i am stuck from few days, i am trying to send sms(that predefined set from my app ) with selected contact to whats app, with the help of stackoverflow i found two method to send sms to `whatsapp`.

**1st method:** one method is forward sms to `whatsapp` well, but not with selected contact, contact can be select from `whatsapp` but i not want that. I want contact also should be select from my app.now

**2nd method:** second method is opposite to first. This method send selected contact to `whatsapp` for sms but not with (predefined sms).
My problem is that i want both things should be passed to `whatsapp` from my app sms+Contact.When i try merge both method gives error. Please Help me 
here is my code for 1st method and 2nd method.

```
    //1st method: for forward sms to whatsapp
        Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        waIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String text = "YOUR TEXT HERE";
        waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        startActivity(waIntent);


    //2nd method: send sms with selected contact but not with predefined sms 
       void openWhatsappContact(String number) {
       Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + number);
       Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
       i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
       startActivity(i);


  //here i am trying to send both SMS and contact from my Android app but not working and get error. 
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + "065214585756");
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hai Good Morning");
        sendIntent.putExtra("chat",true);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Please any one help me.How i can do it.

Comment: I guess  Unfortunately .. Its not p o s s i b l e

Comment: @sajidHussain its not possible yet as whatsapp don't provide such facility of sending text from some other app.

Answer (score 0):

Untill and unless Whatsapp developers expose API s to send messages programmatically it cant be done. As far as i know only Google Now has a special permission for sending messages in Whatsapp, you can check the same in Google Now (Voice message send) .

Let me know if any issues.

Best Regds

Comment: question is not about sending messages its about **sending messages with a particular contact** read the question first  !

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can´t do it. There's no publicly exposed API for whatsapp.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. **WhatsApp** allows the user to pick only contact or group manually , and you cannot change that in any way. Your both methods are fine.

for more details

https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/28000012

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a message to the particular number then you can use this code.
It works for me.

```
// number should be with country code but without plus(+) and any space. For example 919876543210
private void send(String number, String message) {
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    sendIntent.putExtra("jid", number + "@s.whatsapp.net");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

It will directly open whatsapp with the particular then you just need to press Enter or Tap send button.

Enjoy it.